# Update expiration date of an existing cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies

In a controller action, I create a cookie and set the `Expires` option:

```
CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions();
cookieOptions.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("CookieName", "CookieValue", cookieOptions);
```

I can also access the value of a cookie this way:

```
string cookieValue = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["CookieName"];
```

How can I update the expiration date of `CookieName` to `DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);`?

The only way I found is to rerun the code that creates the cookie.  But is there any way to just update the existing cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookie is owned by browser not the server.  Also browser does not send any cookie metadata to server side , only key-values , no path, no expiration time. What you can do is creating a new cookie on server and overwrite existing one , that is by design .